# What's the point of this bitwise XOR?

Tags: c++, arduino, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor

I was trying to understand the arduino library "virtual wire" and I ran into this code:

```
static uint8_t vw_ptt_pin = 10;
static uint8_t vw_ptt_inverted = 0;

// ...

void vw_set_ptt_pin(uint8_t pin)
{
    vw_ptt_pin = pin;
}

void vw_set_ptt_inverted(uint8_t inverted)
{
    vw_ptt_inverted = inverted;
}

// ...

void vw_tx_start()
{
    // ...
    digitalWrite(vw_ptt_pin, true ^ vw_ptt_inverted);
    // ...
}

void vw_tx_stop()
{
    // ...
    digitalWrite(vw_ptt_pin, false ^ vw_ptt_inverted);
    // ...
}
```

I just don't get why he uses `true ^ vw_ptt_inverted` and `false ^ vw_ptt_inverted`. The output of this bitwise operation (integer) doesn't match with the type of the input of the function (boolean). Also whats the point of doing `0 ^ A`? Isn't `0^A==A`?

Comment: This is just random code. Don't try to understand it, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Normally `vw_tx_start()` outputs 1 to the port and `vw_tx_stop()` outputs 0:

```
1 ^ 0 == 1
0 ^ 0 == 0
```

If you set `flag vw_ptt_inverted` to 1,  `vw_tx_start()` will output 0 and `vw_tx_stop()` 1:

```
1 ^ 1 == 0
1 ^ 0 == 1
```

Though `vw_set_ptt_inverted()` should accept boolean type or check it's input, if you set flag to arbitrary number it will not work properly.

For types, in C++ boolean can be implicitly converted to int (true => 1, false => 0) and vice versa (non zero => true, zero => false), so boolean constants converted to integer for xor operation and then result integer converted back to boolean according to rules.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand how the code works, but I still have a question:
Isn't using the bitwise XOR overcomplicating things?
Can't I just use `!vw_ptt_inverted` instead of `true ^ vw_ptt_inverted` and `vw_ptt_inverted` instead of `false ^vw_ptt_inverted`?

Comment: You are right, `false ^ vw_ptt_inverted` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @GabrielAguiar yes you can, people who program for embedded work with binary operations quite often, so looks like this way is more simple and straightforward for them